# SQLite query problem with special character

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a function which is executing a query on a table in SQLite database.I have one what like **" what's your name ?"** .This is stored in a String variable let's say v, I have one query like **"Select * from xyz where question=" ' "+v+" ' "**; .But it is throwing some exception near appos s. Any solution will be appreciated.

Is is showing error : whilke compiling : select * from xyz where quesion='what's your name? '

Comment: Don't describe your code, just paste it here. Specify line on which exception is thrown. Add valuable exception information.

Comment: General advice: Concatenating user-supplied values directly into your query strings (yes, even if you escape quotes) presents a risk for SQL injection attacks. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for information on how to use SQL placeholders in various languages (you haven't specified your programming language) to eliminate this risk.

Comment: Regarding this specific question: The SQL error is caused by the stray single quote in "what's". Other answers have told you how to escape that quote. If their solutions aren't fixing it for you, then we're not going to be able to help you any further until you show us your code so we can see where it's going wrong.

Comment: JAVA is my programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first replace char with this

```
v=v.replaceAll("'","\'");
```

then pass it in your query

```
"select * from xyz where question='"+v+"'";
```

give a shot

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this

```
VALUE = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(VALUE);
"select * from xyz where question="+ VALUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `"select * from xyz where question='"+v+"'"`

Comment: No difference. I f any will you plz help in finding out.

Comment: with first " you end the string.But didn't use + to concat.You have problem with concating string in the code

Comment: no no i just gave space because single quote was not visible.

Comment: pls copy and paste my query and see the result

Comment: Did that not working. same problem.I know I have put extra double qoute.But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all single quotes in v with 2 single quotes :

```
String q = "select * from xyz where question = '" + v.replaceAll("'","''") + "'";
```

Comment: Think I misunderstood your problem :)